# Safe, Sequential And Scalable Counters In Mnesia

Tags: database-design, erlang, mnesia

I am writing an application in Erlang/OTP and want to use sequential counters on a version recording system.

I first implemented them with

```
mnesia:dirty_update_counter
```

but the experience of using it drove out these hard requirements:

The counters must have the following properties:

- be strictly sequential - 1 followed
  by 2 followed by 3 etc, etc
  the sequence is shared across a distributed set of systems and if I
  have you down  as a '3' and you come
  in a '5' I need to know we have lost
  some comms and should resync
- safe with a distributed database

```
mnesia:dirty_update_counter
```

meets neither of these requirements.

How could I implement a sequential database counter?

Comment: Just one question: Do you exactly need this number or just the order? In the latter case you could use a timestamp as order criteria.

mue

Comment: When I get a message and then another one I need to know if I should have got one in the middle - so it has to be strictly sequential.

Comment: So you have messages arriving on different physical machines and you want to id them so you are absolutely certain in which order they arrived?

Comment: Are you sure you won't run into problems such as this one: http://camelcase.blogspot.com/2007/08/cap-theorem.html --- not trying to be negative, just wondering what your availability requirements are, etc.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my comments - the counters need to be safe within a distributed (ie 2/3 node) database which is an instance of a sub-partition of a large partioned database - so I intend to avoid the problems you pointed out that way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since Mnesia data is not guaranteed to replicate atomicly you have to manually lock somehow. I see three alternatives (two with locking and one without):

- Using read locks on the
  table as you request a new version
  number. That implies transactions
  though.
- Use a central server that keeps track
  of the version numbers and increment
  them atomically, for example by
  having a process on one of your nodes
  which you ask for version numbers.
- Synchronize your servers
  with NTP and use timestamps.

Comment: Timestamps are no good because they are not strictly sequential as I said above. If I have 2 transactions that are timestamped I don't know if there is one missing in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about a Message Broker? You could keep it in Erlang by loading up [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com) and setting up a durable queue and persistent messages. Build a consumer that increments a number in the message body by 1 then publishes that new number back to the queue in a new message as it acks the original one.

Not sure it would work for you but it seems like once you manually publish the first message with 1 in the body you would be off and running.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest an erlang process that serves up numbers for you. Since erlang processes messages sequentially you would be guaranteed of getting them in order. Persisting them would be necessary somewhow. The RabbitMQ suggestion above is one way but if you feel like it's overkill then just having the process store to a file periodically should be sufficient. A gen_server should be sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest answer is what you are looking for, simply by getting a write lock (for replicated syncing) and making a transactional function that gets the current value of the counter, increments it and saves it back to the DB. Certainly you will get increased overhead as the system scales, but I would recommend writing a server that does this for you and run that on a subset of the nodes, so the lock contention is not directly linked with the cluster size.